# Is there any difference between these three phrases: capture/win/steal sb's heart?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Do *capture/win/steal someone's heart* mean the same, especially in American English? Or is there perhaps a subtle difference in meaning?

When I say **1)** "Krispy Kreme Donuts will steal your heart" **2)** "Krispy Kreme Donuts will win your heart" or **3)** "Krispy Kreme Donuts will capture your heart"

Do all three sentences mean the same?

Does the phrase "win sb's heart" imply a romantic connotation?

According to my paper dictionary and online dictionaries, there is no difference between these verbs, e.g.:

> [Merriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/win/steal/capture%20one%27s%20heart)
>   **win/steal/capture one's heart**
>   : to cause another person to feel love for one • *He was determined to win/steal/capture her heart*.
>
> [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/steal+heart)
>   ***steal someone's heart***:
>   Fig. to capture someone's affections; to cause someone to fall in love with oneself
>
> [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/win-capture-steal-someone-s-heart)
>   **win/capture/steal someone’s heart**
>   • to make someone start to love you
>
> [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/steal_someone%27s_heart)
>   **steal someone's heart**
>   • *Win someone's love*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, they probably mean the same thing. But the usage may vary based on the context. '*Steal*' sounds more aggressive when compared to '*win*' or '*capture*'.

> Krispy Kreme Donuts will **steal** your heart

This probably is the best among the three to use when it comes to marketing the particular brand of donuts. That's because, '*steal*' will imply that the donuts will, without doubt, taste good. The confidence levels are high and that will positively impact their marketing.

> Krispy Kreme Donuts will **win** your heart

This is much more passive. It fails to create a '*punch*'. By using '*win*', the catchphrase lacks the persuasive power that a marketing campaign should deliver.

You should use '*win*' when the context is light and subtle. For example, "*The Italian **won** their hearts by showing how polite he can be*".

> Krispy Kreme Donuts will **capture** your heart

Although not as passive as '*win*', **capture** also fails to deliver that good impact, when it comes to marketing. Capture can be used to target subtle contexts, for example, "*The aroma of the Colombian fresh ground coffee **captured** her heart*".

In my personal opinion, by using '*capture*', the context switches to a kind of intimate feeling between the subject and the object.